# hitesting the weapons

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have a movieclip on my stage called dude inside the moviclip is a frame with a movie clip called axeframe with yet another movie clip called axe. what i want to do is make a hittest in the axeframe a so that when the axe (only axe not the character) hits an enemy(named enemy) on the ***stage*** he will disappear. this is my code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, axehit);

function axehit(event:Event):void {

if (axe.hitTestObject(enemy)) {
 removeChild(enemy.stage)
}
}
```

it gives me this error

1120: Access of undefined property enemy.if (axe.hitTestObject(enemy)) {

1120: Access of undefined property enemy.removeChild(enemy.stage)

Comment: any better ways of makeing this better/faster/eaier in the future would be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can't just reference to `enemy` without any further specification (it will assume enemy is a child of the movieclip in which you placed the code. Try `stage.enemy` instead, and `this`, or `this.parent` instead of `axe`.
(Assuming enemy is a movieclip on the `stage`, and the code you posted is inside `axe`)
Also, you should change `removeChild(enemy.stage)` to `stage.removeChild(stage.enemy)`, and you should probably look into variable scopes.*

---

Edit: Nope.
Sorry for that, just pretend you didn't read that (Forgot you can't just reference objects through Stage)

To be completely honest with you, this is the way I started as well but it's not the proper approach to flash coding. Firstly, you should try to keep all your code on the main timeline, and not in separate movieclips, in order for it to work together better. Once you get the hang of it, you should check out Object Oriented programming as well. It really increases the workflow and enables you to create bigger and way more complicated scripts.

more edits:

So to put this **on the main timeline**, would require something such as:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(event:Event):void {
    if (axe.hitTestObject(enemy)) {
        this.removeChild(enemy)
    }
}
```

Which is cleaner and more readable (and easier to find) as well. (**Assuming `axe` and `enemy` are movieclips on the main stage**)

Comment: i still get these errors                                           1119: Access of possibly undefined property enemy through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.         1120: Access of undefined property enemy.

Comment: Great :) Good luck on your project ;)